# Need to pass an argument from a function and pass it in JSON payload value

Tags: javascript, cypress

In the below code I need to pass 'id' as an argument of function test_api and pass it in 'const body' as the value of the 'id' key instead of '12345'. How it is possible in Cypress?

```
Cypress.Commands.add("test_api", (id) => {
    const body = {
        "payload": "{\"id\" : \"12345\"}"
    }
    const header = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    cy.request({
         method :'POST',
         url : '/test-api',
         headers : header,
         body : body,
         failOnStatusCode: false})
         .then((response) => {
              const resp = JSON.parse(response.body.payload)
              return resp['key']
    })   
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Cypress.Commands.add("test_api", (id) => {
    const body = {
        payload: JSON.stringify({id})
    }
    const header = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    cy.request({
         method :'POST',
         url : '/test-api',
         headers : header,
         body : body,
         failOnStatusCode: false})
         .then((response) => {
              const resp = JSON.parse(response.body.payload)
              return resp['key']
    })   
  })
})
```

Comment: Why don't you explain what's going on there?

Comment: If I pass like this, const body = {
        payload: JSON.stringify({id})
    } where will I give the key name 'id'

Comment: @eric99 @anuj-abraham
`{ id }` is a good way to write { 'id': id }, in case your key and value name is same you can write it like `{ id }`

for example 

const name = 'hello',
const id = 'myId',

`const data {
    'name': name,
   'id': id
} `

this could be written as 

`const data = {
   name,
   id,
}`
and the fi you will do JSON.stringify both, result will be same

Comment: That's the reason above answer should work fine

Comment: @AnjuAbraham you don't need to give key 'id' in this case. It will work fine and server will get like { id: 'yourId' }